# ASP.Net MVC 5 block download image

Tags: asp.net-mvc, image, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a folder in my site where I save an image and her thumbnail. The image file name is filename.jpg and the thumbnail is filename_thumb.jpg. I want when trying to display the image (not the thumbnail) block the download server. I am working with asp.net mvc 5.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: I'm trying this: routes.Ignore("_Content/image.jpg") but doesn't work.

Comment: what error your are getting?